# Date format in Microsoft Graph using PowerShell and Update-MgGroupEvent

Tags: powershell, microsoft-graph-api

I am writing a PowerShell script to select an MS Group event that I want to add an end date to. Everything works with selection and user input until I get to the point where it's time to update the event. As is often the case for me, the datetime formatting is my nemesis.

Here's what I consider the relevant parts of my code:

```
function AddEndDate ($recurrencePattern, $newEndDate) {
    $patternedRecurrence = @{
        pattern = $recurrencePattern
        range = @{
            endDate = $newEndDate
            type = "endDate"
        }
    }
    return $patternedRecurrence
}

$newEndDate = [DateTime](& $PSScriptRoot\Get-GuiDate.ps1)

$updateRecurrence = AddEndDate $openRecurringEvent.RecurrencePattern $newEndDate

Update-MgGroupEvent -EventId $mostRecentEvent.Id -GroupId $teamID -Recurrence $updateRecurrence
```

Here's what the variables are (might be obvious, but I'm including them here for completeness):

- $recurrencePattern: The recurrence pattern from the event as it is. (Uncertain if it is completely necessary)
- $newEndDate: I am using the utility Get-GuiDate for this and it returns a string which I then cast as a DateTime type.
- $mostRecentEvent: The most recent event that I got from the GetGroupEvents function, filtered to find the event I want.
- $teamID: ID of the MS Team associated with the event.
- $openRecurringEvent: A custom object with data that stores data along the way. The RecurrencePattern property is a straight copy of $mostRecentEvent.Recurrence.Pattern.

So when I run this I get the following error message:

> Update-MgGroupEvent : Recurrence end date can not exceed Sep 1, 4500
> 00:00:00.

Clearly I don't intend for the date to be beyond 4500, but I'm not sure how to get the date in the correct format so that Update-MgGroupEvent can be happy.

1. How do I turn the DateTime that I have into the appropriate format for MS Graph?
2. Or am I missing the target completely and should be taking another approach?

I'm a PowerShell beginner so I don't presume that just because parts of my code work that means I'm right.

John

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to help I got [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/1303165/updating-a-group-event-in-ms-graph-cannot-get-date) I finally got it working. Here's what I did:

1. Used the variable $mostRecentEvent (which contained the results of the event query earlier in the code) and I just updated the values in it.
2. Used `Get-Date($newEndDate) -Format s` to get it in the correct format.

So my code ended up looking like this;

```
$mostRecentEvent.Recurrence.Range.Type = "endDate"
$mostRecentEvent.Recurrence.Range.endDate = Get-Date($newEndDate) -Format s

Update-MgGroupEvent -EventId $mostRecentEvent.Id -GroupId $teamID -Recurrence $mostRecentEvent.Recurrence
```

Answer (score 0):

While I can't test this right now, isn't `$openRecurringEvent.RecurrencePattern` a hashtable? So why aren't you simply assigning the new enddate value?

```
$openRecurringEvent.RecurrencePattern.Range.EndDate = $newEndDate
Update-MgGroupEvent -EventId $mostRecentEvent.Id -GroupId $teamID -Recurrence $openRecurringEvent.RecurrencePattern
```

Naturally you need to make sure your $newEndDate is formatted correctly. Check the `$openRecurringEvent.RecurrencePattern.Range.EndDate` format and do a `.gettype()` on it.

Also, why are you recasting your `$newenddate` as a `[DateTime]`? When I run it, I get a `[Datetime]` object.

```
PS C:\> $tdate = .\get-guidate\Get-GuiDate.ps1
PS C:\> $tdate
Friday, 23 June 2023 12:00:00 AM

PS C:\> $tdate.GetType()
IsPublic IsSerial Name                                     BaseType                                                                                                                  
-------- -------- ----                                     --------                                                                                                                  
True     True     DateTime                                 System.ValueType
```

If your $newEndDate looks similar to the initial version of `$openRecurringEvent.RecurrencePattern.Range.EndDate`, it should work in principle to just manipulate the `$openRecurringEvent.RecurrencePattern` object and splat it back in with the updated value. Or at least any resulting errors might help illuminate the problem better.

Comment: To answer your first question about why I updated a hashtable the way I did: because it's the first time I've used one. So, thanks for showing me a better way.

As for the date casting, I'm not sure. I'm sure I had my reasons at the time - it was probably just one of the many attempts at getting it right. I took out the recasting (I was getting a datetime type, too) but I still get the same error: `Update-MgGroupEvent : Recurrence end date can not exceed Sep 1, 4500 00:00:00.`
I guess MS Graph doesn't like that format.